# Tibco is not receiving Citrus JDBC Message from citrus-test

Tags: jdbc, tibco, citrus-framework

I'm getting to know the citrus framework, so i did some basic tests with the XML DSL till the point where i wanted to test a simple JDBC query with citrus. It doesn't work for XML DSL so i switched to Java DSL, but i am getting the same error.

After a JMS Receiver gets triggered, i do a SQL Query in tibco, if any error applies, my JMS Error Queue gets triggered.
So for any test with Citrus i get a JMS Error Queue Message with the error provided. And MSG-Code in Tibco: `BW-JDBC-100014`

I put the lastest citrus-db driver in `../tibco/tpcl/5.10/jdbc/` and `../tibco/tpcl/5.10/lib/` and i updated the designer.tra file with following content

```
## this will be prepended to tibco.class.path.extended
tibco.env.CUSTOM_CP_EXT ... :%TPCL_HOME%/jdbc/citrus-db-driver-0.2-....-full.jar

# Set CLASS PATH
tibco.env.STD_CP_EXT ... :%TPCL_HOME%/jdbc/citrus-db-driver-0.2-...-full.jar
```

I have no more ideas what to try out, may be i did some basic error?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<exceptiondata>
    <ActivityErrors>
        <ns0:JDBCSQLException xmlns:ns0 = "http://schemas.tibco.com/bw/plugins/jdbc/5.0/jdbcExceptions">
            <msg>"JDBC error reported: (SQLState = null) - java.sql.SQLException: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.consol.citrus.db.driver.exchange.DatabaseResult` out of START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (org.shaded.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"</msg>
            <msgCode>BW-JDBC-100014</msgCode>
            <sqlState/>
            <detailStr>java.sql.SQLException: com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.consol.citrus.db.driver.exchange.DatabaseResult` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (org.shaded.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
            </detailStr>
        </ns0:JDBCSQLException>
    </ActivityErrors>
</exceptiondata>
```

My Testresults are ok like i said, but in my Tibco Designer i get the mentioned error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Citrus Integration Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] Deleting /local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) @ CitrusTest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running de.myProject.ea.MyJdbcTest
10:59:54,419 INFO  BeanDefinitionReader| Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/target/test-classes/citrus-context.xml]
10:59:55,319 INFO              util.log| Logging initialized @1777ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
10:59:55,374 INFO  .EmbeddedJettyServer| == Spark has ignited ...
10:59:55,374 INFO  .EmbeddedJettyServer| >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3307
10:59:55,377 INFO         server.Server| jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_152-b16
10:59:55,402 INFO        server.session| DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
10:59:55,402 INFO        server.session| No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
10:59:55,403 INFO        server.session| node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
10:59:55,442 INFO  er.AbstractConnector| Started ServerConnector@74a8c155{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:3307}
10:59:55,442 INFO         server.Server| Started @1900ms
10:59:55,442 INFO     server.JdbcServer| Started server: jdbcServer_DBName
10:59:55,498 INFO         server.Server| jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 1.8.0_152-b16
10:59:55,529 INFO   ContextHandler.ROOT| Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'WebServer_webservicename-servlet'
10:59:55,529 INFO  ageDispatcherServlet| FrameworkServlet 'WebServer_webservicename-servlet': initialization started
10:59:55,673 INFO  ageDispatcherServlet| FrameworkServlet 'WebServer_webservicename-servlet': initialization completed in 144 ms
10:59:55,673 INFO  ndler.ContextHandler| Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@726a17c4{/,file:///local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/src/main/resources,AVAILABLE}
10:59:55,680 INFO  er.AbstractConnector| Started ServerConnector@2687f956{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:12345}
10:59:55,680 INFO         server.Server| Started @2138ms
10:59:55,680 INFO  ver.WebServiceServer| Started server: WebServer_webservicename
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|        .__  __                       
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|   ____ |__|/  |________ __ __  ______
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| _/ ___\|  \   __\_  __ \  |  \/  ___/
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| \  \___|  ||  |  |  | \/  |  /\___ \ 
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|  \___  >__||__|  |__|  |____//____  >
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|      \/                           \/
10:59:55,714 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| C I T R U S  T E S T S  2.8.0
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| BEFORE TEST SUITE: SUCCESS
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:55,715 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,763 WARN     server.JdbcServer| Unable to create test context factory from Spring application context - using minimal test context factory
10:59:55,765 INFO  .EmbeddedJettyServer| == Spark has ignited ...
10:59:55,765 INFO  .EmbeddedJettyServer| >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3308
10:59:55,765 INFO         server.Server| jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: ...; jvm 1.8.0_152-b16
10:59:55,767 INFO        server.session| DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
10:59:55,767 INFO        server.session| No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
10:59:55,767 INFO        server.session| node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
10:59:55,772 INFO  er.AbstractConnector| Started ServerConnector@13db0f9f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:3308}
10:59:55,772 INFO         server.Server| Started @2231ms
10:59:55,772 INFO     server.JdbcServer| Started server: JdbcServer
10:59:55,816 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,816 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:55,816 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:55,817 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,289 INFO  PurgeJmsQueuesAction| Purged JMS queues
10:59:56,290 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,290 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,290 INFO    actions.EchoAction|  Queues erfolgreich bereinigt! 
10:59:56,291 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,291 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,332 INFO  endpoint.JmsProducer| Message was sent to JMS destination: 'jdbc.trigger'
10:59:56,333 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,333 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,333 INFO    actions.EchoAction| JMS Message was sent to: myJmsJdbcSender
10:59:56,333 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,333 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,429 INFO     server.JdbcServer| GET http://localhost:3308/connection/transaction
10:59:56,440 INFO     server.JdbcServer| POST http://localhost:3308/query
10:59:56,442 INFO  intAdapterController| Received execute query request: select o.value from order_db o where o.orderid=? - (123)
10:59:56,494 INFO  .ChannelSyncProducer| Message was sent to channel: 'JdbcServer.inbound'
10:59:56,530 INFO  TextMessageValidator| XML message validation successful: All values OK
10:59:56,530 INFO  ssageHeaderValidator| Message header validation successful: All values OK
10:59:56,530 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,530 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,530 INFO    actions.EchoAction| SQL Query erfolgreich: select o.value from order_db o where o.orderid=? - (123)
10:59:56,530 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,530 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,533 INFO  .ChannelSyncConsumer| Message was sent to reply channel: 'org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@5c1f6d57'
10:59:56,533 INFO  .ChannelSyncProducer| Received synchronous response from reply channel
10:59:56,533 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,533 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,533 INFO    actions.EchoAction| SQL Antwort erfolgreich.
10:59:56,533 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,601 INFO     server.JdbcServer| GET http://localhost:3308/statement
10:59:56,638 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,639 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| TEST SUCCESS MyJdbcTest (de.myProject.ea)
10:59:56,639 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:56,639 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| AFTER TEST SUITE: SUCCESS
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| CITRUS TEST RESULTS
10:59:56,656 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,657 INFO  port.LoggingReporter|  MyJdbcTest ..................................................... SUCCESS
10:59:56,657 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,657 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| TOTAL: 1
10:59:56,658 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| FAILED:    0 (0.0%)
10:59:56,658 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| SUCCESS:   1 (100.0%)
10:59:56,658 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| 
10:59:56,658 INFO  port.LoggingReporter| ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:59:56,680 INFO  ctOutputFileReporter| Generated test report: target/citrus-reports/citrus-test-results.html
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.943 s - in de.myProject.ea.MyJdbcTest
10:59:56,800 INFO  er.AbstractConnector| Stopped ServerConnector@2687f956{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:12345}
10:59:56,800 INFO   ContextHandler.ROOT| Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'WebServer_webservicename-servlet'
10:59:56,803 INFO  ndler.ContextHandler| Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@726a17c4{/,file:///local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/src/main/resources,UNAVAILABLE}
10:59:56,804 INFO  .EmbeddedJettyServer| >>> Spark shutting down ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ CitrusTest ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /local-home/workspace/myProject/CitrusTest/target/CitrusTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.522 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-12T10:59:57+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/601M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT: Please have some mercy if i missed something important, it's my first post, but a long time stackoverflow-reader. :-)

EDIT2: As i changed the JDBC query to JDBC update (Tibco Tool), it works fine. I don't understand why, if i had to guess it's the sent answer that cannot get properly be read?

Comment: I am not familiar with Citrus framework but for me it looks like citrus framework is only providing database mockup not real database. Tibco BW 5 may not support citrus jdbc driver. Just interested how you setup JDBC connection to citrus database in tibco bW5? Are you able to do "Test connection" from JDBC connection activity?

Comment: I think Tibco BW 5 is supporting the citrus driver, it works fine except this one thing with the SQL query. But correct me someone if i am wrong.

Comment: You are correct with citrus providing database mockup, so that's why i simulate an incoming SQL Query (if matching) and then simulate returning an answer from my jdbc. Thats where it fails, since Tibco is not able to convert my message.

In Tibco i configured my Database with global variables (real data) linked to my JDBC Connection. So then i can put in my citrus config file "nameOfYourConfig.config" the mocked jdbc driver connection. If you start Tibco use the advanced arguments for Tester. 
https://community.tibco.com/questions/tester-advanced-arguments-replace-global-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's a bug, but when i switched to an older version of citrus-db-driver i had no problems anymore with the SQL Query.

So with `citrus-db-driver-0.2-20180506.225718-22-full.jar` it did work but with `citrus-db-driver-0.2.0-20190610.094549-9-full.jar` i had problems running SQL Query in Tibco with simple Select Statement like `'SELECT title from book where id = 123'`.